# I am having trouble with receiving keypresses in C

Tags: c

I am trying out some practice questions, and this is one of them. I think that I am meant to use getch in order to recieve a keypress without the user pressing the enter key, however I have no clue about how to do this. Please help.

Question:
Write a program that counts the number of keys pressed until the user presses the ‘!’ key. 
    When the '!' is pressed the program should display the key-press count on the screen and then terminate.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
    {
int i, counter;
i = 0;
counter = 0;
char input;
while (i==0)
{
    scanf("%c", &input);
    if (input == "!");
    {
        i = 1;
    }
    counter ++;
}
printf("Keystrokes = %d", counter);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The indentions are correct, do not worry.

Comment: You can't do what you want with basic C standard library. You need extra stuff that will depend on your OS (or use another library like *curses*).

Answer (score 2):

Turn on your compiler warnings, and mind them.

```
if (input == "!");
//           ^ ^ ^
if (input == '!')
```

Other than the errors above and needing an ENTER your program should work as is.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work without pressing ENTER KEY. But won't show any input in terminal. But will show how many key pressed after pressing `!` .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, counter;
    i = 0;
    counter = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(getch()=='!')
            break;
        counter++;
    }
    printf("Keystrokes = %d", counter);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI: `<conio.h>` and `getch()` are not described in the C standard.

Comment: @pmg Thanks. I know that but OP want to do with `getch()` not with C standard.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int counter;
    counter = 0;
    char input = '0';

        while (input != '!'){
            scanf("%c", &input);
            if(input != '\n')
                counter ++;
        }

    printf("Keystrokes = %d", counter);
    return 0;
}
```